# Rubyのクラスに関する文法

Tags: ruby, d

Ruby初心者です．
Rubyのクラスに関する文法で質問があります．

クラスの中にクラスを作る方法はあるのでしょうか？
D言語であればUFCSでつながるように参照・更新がしたいです．

ご教授宜しくお願いします．

例えば，以下のような感じでコードを書きたいです．
（以下の例はRubyの文法にはしたがっているとは限りません）

```
class Class1
    class Class2
       def initialize
           @value = 10
       end

       attr_accessor :value
    end
end

class1 = Class1.new
p class1.class2.value  #参照も更新もできる
```

Comment: 「クラスの中にクラスを作る」というよりは「クラスの中に inner クラスのインスタンスを作る」様に見受けられます。例えば、https://paiza.io/projects/e/3XPauQTuwRF0ispRDckotA の様な事でしょうか？

Comment: はい，そのような感じだと思います．metropolisさんにご提示頂いた上記のリンクの15行目の@class2のみ書かれているのは何を意味しているのでしょうか...

Comment: はい、Class2 型のインスタンス(`@class2`)を返しています(`return @class2` という事です)。`p class1.class2` を実行してみると分かるかと思います。

Comment: ご丁寧にありがとうございます．上記のリンクのコードは理解することができました

Answer (score 2, accepted):

端的に答えると、そのようなものは(がんばってどうにかそれっぽく実装しないかぎり)存在しない、と思います。

ruby において、クラスの中にクラスを定義した場合、外部のクラスと内部のクラスの関係は、とあるモジュールとその中に定義したクラスの関係と、ほとんど同じです。この場合、外部のクラス（や、同じような形で外部のモジュール）は、基本的にクラス定数を定義しておく名前空間的な役割しか、言語機能的にもっていません。

質問者さんがやりたいことは、フィールドのコンポジションへの分解的なことかな、と思います。自分がやるとしたら、素直に次のような形になるかなと思います。

```
class Class1
  class Class2
    def initialize
      @value = 10
    end
    attr_reader :value
  end

  def initialize
    @class2 = Class2.new
  end
  attr_reader :class2
end

class1 = Class1.new
class1.class2.value # => 10
```